# php simple xml, loop hrough object, put string in array

Tags: php, xml-parsing

I am getting an XML error for some reason, even though this(beginner) code does what i want it to do.
It fetches strings into an array.

Line 11 results in  "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\pam\w\www\mp\p\lasxml.php on line 11"

```
    <?php           
    $xml = new DOMDocument( "1.0", "ISO-8859-1" );                                                          
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.myepisodes.com/rss.php?feed=mylist&showignored=0&sort=asc&uid=Demerzel&pwdmd5=c6ed54b98a82b1----ac58147cedbde5'); 


    $allaFullStringfranxml = array();                                           
    $i = 0;                                                                 
        do{                                                                 
            $allaFullStringfranxml[] = $xml->channel->item[$i]->title;          
            ++$i;                                                               
        }while(($xml->channel->item[$i]->title) != null);
```

Comment: There's a big space in your load_file URI. That shouldn't be there.

Comment: ah yes, that shouldnt bee there, edited

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are using do-while loop, I think in this case foreach will be better - do while loop is running at least once (even if there is no item). Also you are incrementing `$i` variable and then checking if title `title` of item with `$i` index is `null` - you shouldn't do that without checking if that item really exists.  That should work better for you:

```
foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
    $allaFullStringfranxml[] = (string)$item->title;
}
```

You can also notice here that I'm doing `(string)$item->title` - that will convert title node to string, in other case you'll store node object.

Comment: Thank you so much! ive been trying foreach, but its kind of abstract as a total beginner.

Comment: This should solve your Notice warning too, as it means it won't try and fail to get the final item property. You should accept this answer if it's gone. Welcome to SO!

Comment: Yes, it took care of it. :)   not sure why i did do-while.. late night trial and error